# App installation issue: Oauth error missing_shopify_permission

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have a public (draft) app (standalone), when we are trying to install that application, I am getting an error:

`"Oauth error missing_shopify_permission: read_customers"`.

I am not able to pinpoint the error. The Url getting generated for the installation is: `https://<Store>.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&scope=read_products%2Cread_orders%2Cread_customers%2Cread_script_tags%2Cwrite_script_tags&redirect_uri=<callback_url>&state=3e1b464a3c5a82bddbe29764f78720`

It is visible that "read_customers" permission is present in the scopes (url param).

Even if the permission was missing, it should have launched the installation page without the "read_customers" permission. Installation works fine in the other staging/test environment.
I am using [shopify_python_api](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api) to generate permission url

Any input will help us to debug and resolve the issue.